# Animating a component's instantiation in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, animation, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to perform an animation when I instantiate a component. This is the situation: I've got many cards with a "Comments" button, and when I press it, a new component "Comments" is inserted in the card, expanding it while showing all of these comments.

Well, now I want that card to expand slowly, with an animation. For this purpose, I downloaded the web-animations.js and web-animations-map.js, following [this tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/using-the-web-animations-api-in-ionic-2/). Then, I made a single test, trying to do an animation that sets the opacity from 0.1 to 1 in 300ms:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'comments',
   templateUrl: 'comments.html',
   animations: [
     trigger('openAnm', [
       state('closed', style({
         opacity: 0.1
       })),
       state('open', style({
         opacity: 1
       })),
       transition('closed => open', animate('300ms ease-in')),
       transition('open => closed', animate('300ms ease-in')),
     ])
   ]
})

export class Comments{

  @Input() commentList;
  listLimit;
  animationState = 'closed';

   constructor(){
     this.listLimit = 4;
     setTimeout(
      this.animationState = 'open',
      50
     );

   }
```

I assigned the @openAnm trigger to the main div of my code:

```
<div [@openAnm]="animationState">
   // more code...
</div>
```

... which I call from this button in the parent view:

```
<button ion-button item-right icon-right  clear color="dark" *ngIf="card.type != 3" (click)="switchVisible(card.id)">
        // more code...

        // my custom component for the comments section
<comments *ngIf="viewCommentsFrom === card.id" [commentList]=getComments(card.id)></comments>
```

Everythineg works, except the animation (dammit!). I think that my call to the animation's trigger is not correct, since it seems to be meant to be used in buttons and so, but I don't know how I can call that animation from the parent view's button, so the component performs the animation in its instantiation.

Any help? Thanks!